# Iterate Query Result in SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I need to query a table that contains another query that I then need to execute, get the results, and store those results in another table. I will not know what, or how many, columns are returned from this query, but I must be able to map the unknown columns to columns in my results table. I do know that the query can contain anywhere from 1 to 20 columns which need to map to my results table as RSLT_1 up to RSLT_20.

For Example, let's say the query returns 5 columns. I need to iterate over the results and map column1 to RSLT_1, column2 to RSLT_2, etc. Then store those results in my result table

I have this logic already written in C# which was trivial since I can loop over columns to determine how many exist. I don't know how to do that in a stored procedure. Any ideas?

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your query will return how many records?  Let say 1 record, n columns.  Run your query, store result in a temp table.  Run a second query to unpivot, and insert into final table (if you cannot include a unpivot in the first query).

Comment: You also can run this query to determine columns in your temp table, and run a cursor for each columns : `select * from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#tmp');`

Comment: @DanielBlais I'm not familiar with unpivot. looking through some examples, I'm failing to see how it would work in my situation. Querying sys columns makes sense though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot write you a complete answer, because I don't know your queries/tables.  Here main lines of what I'm thinking about.  You have to complete for your needs.  But keep in mind, cursor is slow and generally not recommended in production.

```
select * into #tmp from <sourceQuery>

declare @columnName varchar(100)
declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare c cursor for
select name from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#tmp')

open c

fetch next from c into @columnName

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    select @columnName

    set @sql = N'insert into <targetTable> (valueColumn) select ' + @columnName + 'from #tmp'
    exec @sql

    fetch next from c into @columnName
end
close c
deallocate c

drop table #tmp
```